# Perform an action when a number of checkboxes are checked

Tags: android, checkbox, imageview, display

My app have 10 checkboxes, when 5 checkboxes is checked i want display a picture in a ImageView below. But i dont know how to code it. if someone here can help me with this code i will be really greatful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class babyconquistas extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText conqtext1, conqtext2,
Button button;
ImageView img, img1;
CheckBox conq1, conq2, conq3, conq4, conq5, conq6, conq7, conq8, conq9, conq10;
int cbCounter1=0, cbCounter2=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_babyconquistas);

    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgconq2);
    img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgconq4);

    conq1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.conq1);
    conq2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.conq2);
    conq3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.conq3);
    conq4 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.conq4);
    conq5 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.conq5);


    conq6 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.conq6);
    conq7 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.conq7);
    conq8 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.conq8);
    conq9 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.conq9);
    conq10 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.conq10);


    conqtext1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.conq1text);
    conqtext2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.conq2text);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.salvar);

    conq1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
             if(isChecked){
                 cbCounter1 = cbCounter1 + 1;
             } else {
                 cbCounter1 = cbCounter1 - 1;
             }
             if(cbCounter1 == 5) {
                  img.setImageResource(R.drawable.img);
                  //or if you want to handle it with visibility
                  img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             }
        }
    });

    conq2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
             if(isChecked){
                 cbCounter1 = cbCounter1 + 1;
             } else {
                 cbCounter1 = cbCounter1 - 1;
             }
             if(cbCounter1 == 5) {
                  img.setImageResource(R.drawable.img);
                  //or if you want to handle it with visibility
                  img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             }
        }
    });

    conq3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
             if(isChecked){
                 cbCounter1 = cbCounter1 + 1;
             } else {
                 cbCounter1 = cbCounter1 - 1;
             }
             if(cbCounter1 == 5) {
                  img.setImageResource(R.drawable.img);
                  //or if you want to handle it with visibility
                  img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             }
        }
    });

    conq4.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
             if(isChecked){
                 cbCounter1 = cbCounter1 + 1;
             } else {
                 cbCounter1 = cbCounter1 - 1;
             }
             if(cbCounter1 == 5) {
                  img.setImageResource(R.drawable.img);
                  //or if you want to handle it with visibility
                  img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             }
        }
    });

    conq5.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
             if(isChecked){
                 cbCounter1 = cbCounter1 + 1;
             } else {
                 cbCounter1 = cbCounter1 - 1;
             }
             if(cbCounter1 == 5) {
                  img.setImageResource(R.drawable.img);
                  //or if you want to handle it with visibility
                  img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             }
        }
    });

    conq6.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
             if(isChecked){
                 cbCounter2 = cbCounter2 + 1;
             } else {
                 cbCounter2 = cbCounter2 - 1;
             }
             if(cbCounter2 == 5) {
                  img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.img);
                  //or if you want to handle it with visibility
                  img1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             }
        }
    });

            conq7.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
             if(isChecked){
                 cbCounter2 = cbCounter2 + 1;
             } else {
                 cbCounter2 = cbCounter2 - 1;
             }
             if(cbCounter2 == 5) {
                  img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.img);
                  //or if you want to handle it with visibility
                  img1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             }
        }
    });

    conq8.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
             if(isChecked){
                 cbCounter2 = cbCounter2 + 1;
             } else {
                 cbCounter2 = cbCounter2 - 1;
             }
             if(cbCounter2 == 5) {
                  img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.img);
                  //or if you want to handle it with visibility
                  img1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             }
        }
    });

    conq9.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
             if(isChecked){
                 cbCounter2 = cbCounter2 + 1;
             } else {
                 cbCounter2 = cbCounter2 - 1;
             }
             if(cbCounter2 == 5) {
                  img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.img);
                  //or if you want to handle it with visibility
                  img1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             }
        }
    });

    conq10.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
             if(isChecked){
                 cbCounter2 = cbCounter2 + 1;
             } else {
                 cbCounter2 = cbCounter2 - 1;
             }
             if(cbCounter2 == 5) {
                  img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.img);
                  //or if you want to handle it with visibility
                  img1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             }
        }
    });

}
```

This code will do the task. And if you need to store the information in sharedPref, then you can store the counter value and checked, checkboxes info, then on page load you need to populate all the data of checked checkboxes and the counter

Comment: THE CODE WORKED AS WELL! THANK YOU SO MUCH, BUT I REALLY DONT HAVE IDEA NOW HOW I STORE IT IN SharedPref, but again thank you.

Comment: You have savePreferences function in your code, you can store status for every checkbox by using the function 
savePreferences("checkboxName", chekcboxStatus); perform this on checkbox checkedListener and update it if its checked or unchecked, Then use your loadPreferences function, that looks fine for repopulating the data

Answer (score 0):

You can add checkedListener to all checkboxes, and initialize a counter for checkboxes.
Check update the counter on checking of every checkbox and when counter reaches the count 5 do your operation which you need

```
checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(isChecked) {
               checkBoxCounter = checkboxCounter + 1;
               if(checkBoxCounter == 5)
                 //do your imageview task here;
                 imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_image);
            } else {
               //if checkbox is unchecked
               checkBoxCounter = checkBoxCounter - 1;
            }
        }
    });
```

Place this code in all your checkbox onCheckedListener

Comment: Hello, this code dont worked for me, my code dont have a onCkeckedListener it is based in strings for save the state. If you take a little time for help me i be so thankful. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class babyconquistas extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText conqtext1, conqtext2,
Button button;
ImageView img, img1;
CheckBox conq1, conq2, conq3, conq4, conq5, conq6, conq7, conq8, conq9, conq10;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_babyconquistas);

    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgconq2);
    img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgconq4);

    conq1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.conq1);
    conq2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.conq2);
    conq3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.conq3);
    conq4 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.conq4);
    conq5 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.conq5);


    conq6 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.conq6);
    conq7 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.conq7);
    conq8 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.conq8);
    conq9 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.conq9);
    conq10 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.conq10);


    conqtext1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.conq1text);
    conqtext2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.conq2text);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.salvar);
    loadSavedPreferences();

}


//checkboxes
private void loadSavedPreferences() {
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    boolean cbValue1 = sp.getBoolean("CHECKBO1", false);
    boolean cbValue2 = sp.getBoolean("CHECKBO2", false);
    boolean cbValue3 = sp.getBoolean("CHECKBO3", false);
    boolean cbValue4 = sp.getBoolean("CHECKBO4", false);
    boolean cbValue5 = sp.getBoolean("CHECKBO5", false);
    boolean cbValue6 = sp.getBoolean("CHECKBO6", false);
    boolean cbValue7 = sp.getBoolean("CHECKBO7", false);
    boolean cbValue8 = sp.getBoolean("CHECKBO8", false);
    boolean cbValue9 = sp.getBoolean("CHECKBO9", false);
    boolean cbValue10 = sp.getBoolean("CHECKBO10", false);


    if (cbValue1) {
        conq1.setChecked(true);

    } else {
        conq1.setChecked(false);
    }
    if (cbValue2) {
        conq2.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        conq2.setChecked(false);
    }
    if (cbValue3) {
        conq3.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        conq3.setChecked(false);
    }
    if (cbValue4) {
        conq4.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        conq4.setChecked(false);
    }
    if (cbValue5) {
        conq5.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        conq5.setChecked(false);
    }
    if (cbValue6) {
        conq6.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        conq6.setChecked(false);
    }
    if (cbValue7) {
        conq7.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        conq7.setChecked(false);
    }
    if (cbValue8) {
        conq8.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        conq8.setChecked(false);
    }
    if (cbValue9) {
        conq9.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        conq9.setChecked(false);
    }
    if (cbValue10) {
        conq10.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        conq10.setChecked(false);
    }


}


private void savePreferences(String key, boolean value) {
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sp.edit();
    edit.putBoolean(key, value);
    edit.commit();
}

private void savePreferences(String key, String value) {
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sp.edit();
    edit.putString(key, value);
    edit.commit();
}

public void Salvar(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    savePreferences("N1", conqtext1.getText().toString());
    savePreferences("N2", conqtext2.getText().toString());


    savePreferences("CHECKBO1", conq1.isChecked());
    savePreferences("CHECKBO2", conq2.isChecked());
    savePreferences("CHECKBO3", conq3.isChecked());
    savePreferences("CHECKBO4", conq4.isChecked());
    savePreferences("CHECKBO5", conq5.isChecked());
    savePreferences("CHECKBO6", conq6.isChecked());
    savePreferences("CHECKBO7", conq7.isChecked());
    savePreferences("CHECKBO8", conq8.isChecked());
    savePreferences("CHECKBO9", conq9.isChecked());
    savePreferences("CHECKBO10", conq10.isChecked());



}
```

there are 10 checkboxes.

if this first group of 5 checkboxes is ALL CHECKED, DISPLAY THE ImageView img

and the second group of 5 checkboxes, if this 5 checkboxes is all checked, display the ImageViw img1

i hope you understand and i am really thankfull for take your time for help me, thank you sou much really, and if is more easy and if you want of course, i have teamViewer.